# What is the proper way to compile using gcc with libs/headers?

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker

My first example does not work, but my second example does work. So this leads me to ask what is the proper way to compile when linking? Is there more information about proper linking?

Non-working: `gcc $(curl-config --libs --cflags) prog.c -o prog`

Working: `gcc prog.c $(curl-config --libs --cflags) -o prog`

Comment: The working way is the correct way.  You specify libraries after object files.  If you specify the libraries first, you don't get the symbols resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C compiler — it doesn't much matter whether it is GCC or any other compiler — is a complex creature.  It actually invokes separate processes to do different parts of the work.  There's the parser, which may (these days, usually does) include the preprocessor part, then there's code generation, usually to assembler, then object generation by the assembler, and finally program linking (normally by a program called `ld`, for loader).  The detailed organization can be different; the key point here is that the loader operates on the object files created by the earlier phases, and on the libraries that it is told to work with.

When you write the invocation to link the executable, you may or may not also compile code to object files.  In your example, you do compile `prog.c` to `prog.o`; often, the link command only lists object files and not any source files.

The linker is invoked with options (and possibly object files) added by the C compiler, followed by the object files and library and linking related options in the order you list them on the command line, plus any libraries that it adds itself.

There are two types of linking — static and dynamic.  With static linking, the executable contains all the object code that it will use at runtime, except for anything that is dynamically loaded at runtime.  The linker process the object files and libraries as it encounters them.  Often, the first object file is called something like `crt0.o` and is provided by the compiler; it contains a reference to `main()`.  The linker processes object files by noting the symbols it defines and the symbols it references that are not defined.

For static linking, it scans libraries as it encounters them; if the library provides a symbol that is currently undefined, it pulls in the relevant code from the library, and rescans as necessary to find other symbols that are referenced but not yet defined.  If the only undefined symbol is `main()` and the library does not contain a `main()` (that's normal), then the library is skipped in effect.

For dynamic linking (using shared object or dynamically linked libraries, aka DLLs), it used to be the case (on some machines) that if you mentioned a library on the link line, all the symbols were automatically treated as defined, whether they were used or not.  More recently, the compilers ignore a library if it does not contain any relevant symbols at the point in the link process where it is scanned.

Your working example shows the correct linking order — libraries after object files.  Granted, in your example command line, you list a source file, but the compiler converts the command to reference the object file it just created from the source, and lists the libraries and other linker flags in the sequence as on the command line.  If you had an old-style linker that recorded the use of a shared object regardless of whether it satisfied any undefined references, the 'non-working' line would also link OK.  However, it was never reliable; if any of the libraries was a static library, you would run usually run into problems.

So, the rule is simple:

- List object files before libraries when linking programs.

It always works — old and new linkers, static and dynamic libraries.  Doing it any other way is likely to fail on some platforms, sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

This is the gcc syntax. I hope you understand why the first one is not working and the second one is:

GCC syntax

> $ gcc [options] [source files] [object files] [-o output file]